# Why are Quorum and Convention part of the Candidate Score?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, candidate-score

The [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) badge is required in order to be eligible as a moderator candidate and it is impossible to have the Convention badge without having first earned the [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) badge. This means that every candidate will have both of these badges.

Since they aren't helpful in distinguishing between the candidates, I'm not sure why they are included in the candidate score calculation. So why are the Quorum and Convention badges part of the candidate score?

Comment: Similarly, the minimum reputation is at least 3k for a candidate score of 3.

Comment: Why do you think active and positive participation in Meta isn't useful in distinguishing between candidates?

Comment: @sr28 the OP is asking why they are included if they are _prerequisites for candidacy_.  If every candidate must have those badges, then it's not special for them anymore.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - ok, fair point. Presumably it would still be flagged though as a pre-requisite so that voters would be aware of the 'minimum level' of a candidate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The candidate score is calculated in the same way for all Stack Exchange sites. But [almost](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/2) [all](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/4) [sites](https://serverfault.com/election/5) do not require Convention to be a candidate (nor do they require 3000 reputation, as mentioned by @ryanyuyu); Stack Overflow is rather special in this regard.

I suppose that keeping the score calculation consistent over all sites is more important/easy than the fact that only for Stack Overflow,

> they aren't helpful in distinguishing between the candidates

Comment: No other sites have any requirements other than the minimum 300 reputation (which is heightened to 3000 on Stack Overflow) and not being suspended in the past year (which is somewhat new and not present in all election pages).

Comment: Actually, Ask Ubuntu does have the requirement of having to sign the Ubuntu Code of Conduct (or something, I think that's what it's called), but that doesn't have anything to do with our system and was a result of the initial integration with Ubuntu.

Comment: Huh! Why I'm missing these badges at my meta profile??

Comment: Quorom and Convention are in some sense Meta badges, but they're awarded at the main site. This is slightly confusing to me as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel I just saw that now. THX anyways.